Using hidden API to scrape website with JavaScript pager
Website https://www.supralift.com/uk/itemsearch/results uses a JavaScript based pager which doesn´t expose any parameters in url which I could alter and navigate this way through the website.
Looking into "Network" tab of Chrome console I see, that website exposes also some relatively complete information under url /api/search/item/summary. Calling this API endpoint returns me however empty result:
{
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Method Not Allowed",
  "status": 405,
  "detail": "Method 'GET' is not supported.",
  "instance": "/api/search/item/summary"
}

How can I use this hidden API to scrape the website?
Many thanks in advance.

Are you asking about RSelenium?

From Network tab of DevTools you can see the actual request method, in this case it's POST and not GET, so httr::GET(), for example, would not be much of a use here. With a POST request you are usually expected to include a payload, in this case it would be a JSON with search parameters (check Network > Payload in DevTools).
To make the same request in R, you could start by copying request as cURL and translating it through https://curlconverter.com/r/ or similar.
Or if httr2 is also OK, with httr2::curl_translate().
Request method & Copy as cURL (go for bash if it's meant to be an input for some conversion tool, even in Windows):

Following is based on a httr2::curl_translate() output, though in this case it's basically just a convenient shortcut to get a valid payload, using req_body_raw() automatically sets request method to POST. httr2 also provides tools to perform requests iteratively, next request being based on the response of current response,  e.g. cycling though pages while checking if we have reached the final page.
req_perform_iterative() is used with iterate_with_offset() helper to generate a next request based on the current response, resp_pages is anonymous function to extract totalPages value from the first JSON response, resp_complete checks if last is set in the JSON response. Iterator stops once resp_complete returns TRUE or maximum number of requests (max_reqs) is made.
library(httr2)

# prepare 1st request object, size increased
req <- request("https://www.supralift.com/api/search/item/summary") |> 
  req_url_query(
    size = "2000",
    page = "0",
  ) |> 
  req_body_raw('{"searchType":null,"bundleId":null,"identification":{"slNumber":null,"serialNumber":null,"supplierProductNumber":null,"slOrSupplierProductNumber":null},"configuration":{"buildClass":null,"manufacturer":null,"buildSeries":null,"acDriven":null,"powerUnit":null,"fuelType":null,"mastType":null,"gearBox":null,"tyres":null,"typeSearch":null},"buildDates":{"month":null,"year":{"from":null,"to":null}},"dimensions":{"overallHeight":{"from":null,"to":null},"workingHours":{"from":null,"to":null},"loadCentreOfGravity":{"from":null,"to":null},"capacity":{"from":null,"to":null},"forkLength":{"from":null,"to":null},"towingCapacity":{"from":null,"to":null}},"price":{"price":{"from":null,"to":null,"currency":"GBP"}},"cabin":{"cabin":null,"height":{"from":null,"to":null},"platformHeight":{"from":null,"to":null}},"engine":{"manufacturer":null,"power":null},"battery":{"exists":null,"manufacturer":null,"batteryType":null,"voltage":{"from":null,"to":null},"capacity":{"from":null,"to":null},"buildDates":null},"batteryCharger":{"exists":null,"manufacturer":null,"voltage":{"from":null,"to":null},"current":{"from":null,"to":null},"buildDates":{"month":null,"year":{"from":null,"to":null}}},"location":{"distance":100,"postCode":null,"region":null,"countryState":null,"country":null,"countryOrNull":null},"container":{"containerType":null,"hubhoehe8Z3":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z4":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z5":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z7":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z8":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I3":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I4":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I5":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I6":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I7":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I8":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I3":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I4":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I5":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I6":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I7":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I8":{"from":null,"to":null}},"offerDetails":{"offerBegin":null,"maxOfferAge":null,"activationDate":null,"offerFormat":null,"dealsOnly":null,"imagesOnly":null,"offerType":"SALE"},"additionalHydraulic":{"toValve":null,"complete":null},"liftAttributes":{"initialLift":null,"liftHeight":{"from":null,"to":null},"freeLift":{"from":null,"to":null},"liftPower":null},"isLicensedDealerOnly":null,"warranty":{"from":null,"to":null},"qualityRating":null,"attachments":null,"accessories":null,"customFields":null,"specialAttributes":{"explosionProof":null,"stainlessSteel":null,"autonomousMobileRobot":null},"freightTerm":null,"itemStatus":[],"backendSearch":false}', "application/json")

# perform series of requests, increase `page` parameter until 
# `resp_complete` returns TRUE or when reaching `max_reqs`
resps <- 
  req_perform_iterative(
    req, 
    next_req = iterate_with_offset(
      param_name =  "page", 
      start = 0,
      resp_pages       = \(resp) resp_body_json(resp)$totalPages,
      resp_complete    = \(resp) resp_body_json(resp)$last,
      ),
    # generate just first 2 requests as an example
    max_reqs = 2
    )
#> Iterating ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 50% | ETA: 3s

# list of responses:
resps
#> [[1]]
#> <httr2_response>
#> POST https://www.supralift.com/api/search/item/summary?size=2000&page=0
#> Status: 200 OK
#> Content-Type: application/json
#> Body: In memory (2043726 bytes)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <httr2_response>
#> POST https://www.supralift.com/api/search/item/summary?size=2000&page=1
#> Status: 200 OK
#> Content-Type: application/json
#> Body: In memory (1933115 bytes)

All data in a single frame, 2000(size) * 2(max_reqs) = 4000 rows :
resps_data(resps, \(resp) resp_body_json(resp, simplifyVector = TRUE)$content) |> 
  tibble::as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 4,000 × 18
#>    id           slNo type  manufacturer powerUnit buildClass mastType liftHeight
#>    <chr>       <int> <chr> <chr>        <chr>     <chr>      <chr>         <int>
#>  1 66f8d101f… 1.29e7 R14S  LINDE        ELEKTRO   SCHUBMAST… DREIFACH       6250
#>  2 66f8ccfaf… 1.29e7 EPL1… WEITERE      ELEKTRO   NIEDERHUB… <NA>            115
#>  3 66f8c894f… 1.29e7 27823 JUNGHEINRICH ELEKTRO   WEITERE    DREIFACH       5500
#>  4 66f8c886f… 1.29e7 27799 JUNGHEINRICH ELEKTRO   WEITERE    DREIFACH       5000
#>  5 66f8c595f… 1.29e7 T401… BOBCAT       DIESEL    TELESKOPA… <NA>          17000
#>  6 66f8c4e7f… 1.29e7 TFG … JUNGHEINRICH GAS       VIERRADFR… DREIFACH       5000
#>  7 66f8b525f… 1.29e7 EFG … JUNGHEINRICH ELEKTRO   VIERRADFR… DREIFACH       6000
#>  8 66f81676f… 1.28e7 R16G  LINDE        ELEKTRO   SCHUBMAST… <NA>           6210
#>  9 66f80016f… 1.29e7 C500… COMBILIFT    ELEKTRO   SEITENSTA… DREIFACH       6000
#> 10 66f80015f… 1.29e7 H30D… LINDE        DIESEL    VIERRADFR… ZWEIFACH       3760
#> # ℹ 3,990 more rows
#> # ℹ 10 more variables: workingHours <int>, capacity <int>, yearOfBuild <int>,
#> #   company <df[,6]>, offerType <chr>, isNew <lgl>, price <df[,4]>,
#> #   qualityRating <int>, images <list>, specialRating <df[,4]>

Created on 2024-09-29 with reprex v2.1.1

mangusl This is an excellent solution and perfectly explained. I learned a lot from your post about using some of advanced HTTR2 functions and in general about approach to use a hidden API to get the data from website. Thank you so much mangusl. To match your solution I updated the title and body of this question. I still want to learn how to navigate the javascript pager on this site using read_html_live() function but I will post this as a separate question. Many thanks once again.

Based on your question you said this endpoint /api/search/item/summary exposed some relatively complete information. Still, the server showed 405 Method not allowed, well this error occurs because the server is accepting only POST Requests (you can see the Allow: Response header showing POST values only, ). and here is the full POST Request with the json body:
POST /api/search/item/summary?size=100&page=0&sort=price,asc HTTP/2
Host: www.supralift.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.supralift.com/
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.supralift.com
Content-Length: 2664
Origin: https://www.supralift.com
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Priority: u=4
Te: trailers

{"searchType":null,"bundleId":null,"identification":{"slNumber":null,"serialNumber":null,"supplierProductNumber":null,"slOrSupplierProductNumber":null},"configuration":{"buildClass":null,"manufacturer":null,"buildSeries":null,"acDriven":null,"powerUnit":null,"fuelType":null,"mastType":null,"gearBox":null,"tyres":null,"typeSearch":null},"buildDates":{"month":null,"year":{"from":null,"to":null}},"dimensions":{"overallHeight":{"from":null,"to":null},"workingHours":{"from":null,"to":null},"loadCentreOfGravity":{"from":null,"to":null},"capacity":{"from":null,"to":null},"forkLength":{"from":null,"to":null},"towingCapacity":{"from":null,"to":null}},"price":{"price":{"from":null,"to":null,"currency":"GBP"}},"cabin":{"cabin":null,"height":{"from":null,"to":null},"platformHeight":{"from":null,"to":null}},"engine":{"manufacturer":null,"power":null},"battery":{"exists":null,"manufacturer":null,"batteryType":null,"voltage":{"from":null,"to":null},"capacity":{"from":null,"to":null},"buildDates":null},"batteryCharger":{"exists":null,"manufacturer":null,"voltage":{"from":null,"to":null},"current":{"from":null,"to":null},"buildDates":{"month":null,"year":{"from":null,"to":null}}},"location":{"distance":100,"postCode":null,"region":null,"countryState":null,"country":null,"countryOrNull":null},"container":{"containerType":null,"hubhoehe8Z3":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z4":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z5":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z7":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z8":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I3":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I4":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I5":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I6":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I7":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe8Z6I8":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I3":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I4":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I5":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I6":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I7":{"from":null,"to":null},"hubhoehe9Z6I8":{"from":null,"to":null}},"offerDetails":{"offerBegin":null,"maxOfferAge":null,"activationDate":null,"offerFormat":null,"dealsOnly":null,"imagesOnly":null,"offerType":"SALE"},"additionalHydraulic":{"toValve":null,"complete":null},"liftAttributes":{"initialLift":null,"liftHeight":{"from":null,"to":null},"freeLift":{"from":null,"to":null},"liftPower":null},"isLicensedDealerOnly":null,"warranty":{"from":null,"to":null},"qualityRating":null,"attachments":null,"accessories":null,"customFields":null,"specialAttributes":{"explosionProof":null,"stainlessSteel":null,"autonomousMobileRobot":null},"freightTerm":null,"itemStatus":[],"backendSearch":false}

What tool you should use to capture such a request?
Well, I used a proxy tool called Burp Suite by port swigger and it is very helpful for both developers and pentester here
if you're interested in the burp suite then follow these steps:

Download the community version (because it's free).
Download the Firefox/chrome extension called Foxyproxy. (search Foxypoxy on Google)
Set up your burp proxy with the browser. (with the help of the Foxyproxy extension)
Upload the burp ca certificate generated by the burp suite on your target browser. (in your browser: Settings --> search certificates, google it for a better solution).

Thats it!
if you encounter any issues while setting up Burp Suite then don't forget to google it.
Hope this will help.
Thanks
